# Laravel local disk append() taking up a lot of memory

Tags: php, laravel, file, memory

```
Storage::disk('local')
         ->append('/newsletter_lists/'.$contact_file_name.'.csv',
                $contact->email.','.$contact->salutation.','.$contact->lastname.','.$contact->unsubscribelink.','.$contact->bonus
          );
```

This is the code in Laravel that is writing to csv file inside a foreach loop (chunk loading from database).
But as far as I know the `append()` method, is opening the file everytime, loads the content in memory, adds the new line and saves the file again, which with a large number of records (65 000) takes a long time.
I am trying to find a way to append to the end of the file without loading the contents in memory if possible or am I am taking the wrong approach here?

Comment: If you don't mind using "vanilla" php then have a look at `fopen` with `a+b` mode.

Comment: @d3L I don't mind using plain php, fopen(a+b) I know that it appends to end of the file in binary mode, I just could not find in the documentation what happens regarding memory and speed when php opens the file. But will do a quick benchmark to see if there difference in speed.

Comment: Looks like the idea of `append` writing to the end of a file in Flysystem has been worked on, but not implemented yet: https://github.com/thephpleague/flysystem/pull/696

Comment: @1000Nettles yes you are right, in the pull request I can see more questions then actually helping the contributor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I took the @d3L advice and used plain php to append to files and not to use the append() method of laravel, which is loading the content everytime it has to append a line.

```
$file = fopen(Storage::disk('local')->path('test.csv'), "a+b");
```

Comment: I write a file from Redis, and it took many minutes to finish. I have applied the change and it does it instantly, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

For laravel you can use the `File` facade which uses the `Filesystem` class rather than the `FilesystemAdapter` which is limited because it needs to use drivers which do not necessarily have the `append` feature and thus it has to implement it's own by reading the file and outputting it again which is very inefficient.

```php
File::append(Storage::disk('local')->path('test.csv'), PHP_EOL."text to append")
```

The former doesn't have this limitation and under the hood uses

```php
file_put_contents($path, $data_to_append, FILE_APPEND);
```