# How to append string to file without new line break using storage laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

trying to add strings in a file on the same line using `Storage:: disk('local')->append()` method but in the output file I'm getting each string on a new line

what i did is:

```
$string = "first-"; 
Storage::disk('local')->append('filename', $string);
$string = "second"; 
Storage::disk('local')->append('filename', $string);
```

and the output file was

```
first-
second
```

but I'm trying to get the file without line breaks like

```
first-second
```

Comment: Not sure if there's a built-in method to do that, but you could try a longer approach, get the contents of the file, like `$contents = file_get_contents(...)`, append in `PHP`, via `$contents .= 'second';`, then put the whole string into the file. (or something similar)

Comment: the file will be a big file and don't want to open it and loaded in the memory

Comment: Yeah, fair point. You can see all the methods available for the `FileSystem` class (extension of `Storage::disk()` facade method) here: https://laravel.com/api/5.8/Illuminate/Contracts/Filesystem/Filesystem.html#method_append. At a glance, I don't see anything, but do some digging, might find something that works.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54659226/laravel-local-disk-append-taking-up-a-lot-of-memory check that answer. unfortunately append reads whole data

Comment: after testing, i ended up using the php "file_put_contents" function, it's doing the job and without filling the memory

Answer (score 20):

`append()` using `FilesystemAdapter`

```php
public function append($path, $data, $separator = PHP_EOL)
```

> **`PHP_EOL`** is ostensibly used to find the newline character in a cross-platform-compatible way.

So, you can use :

```php
Storage::disk('local')->append('filename', $string, null);
```